# Interpreting the lingo of a definition

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras

### [image]

**The Terms I grew up with:**

---

A bounded linear operator $U$ on a Hilbert space $H$ is a **partial isometry** if there exists a subspace $M$ of $H$ such that $\|Ux\| = \|x\|$ for all $x\in M$, and $Ux = 0$ for all $x\in M^{\perp}$.

$M$ is called the **initial space** of $U$ and $V(M)$ is called the **final space**.

---

Am I correct to say that the definition (particularly line 3 and 4) just require $U$ to have the same initial and final space as $P\otimes 1$ for some projection $P$ on $H_{\mu}$?

---

I didn't give much background but I can supply more if it would help, just let me know.

The source is *Enock & Schwartz - Kac Algebras and Duality of Locally Compact Groups*.

Comment: The link to the picture does not work

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.  I couldn't tell because it works for me.  I'll see if I can figure out what's wrong.  I guess that's why I've got no answer yet. :)

Comment: I tried hosting the picture with a link instead.  I hope it works now.

Comment: It works now. I would say the answer is YES